# Auto execute a program that plays music

Tags: cron, python, programming

as mentionned above, I would like to execute a programme that plays music at certain hour automatically. I tried using crontab but no outcome. This is what I put in crontab: 
 
 8 15 30 3 4 python play_music.py

Without the scheduler, the python script is working. I wonder if using crontab is a solution to my problem as crontab might execute the program in its environment.
 Does any one have an idea or other solutions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `python /fullpath/to/play_music.py` as the cron user will not know where your python script lives. You are correct that running from cron will be in a different environment, check your permissions.

Answer (score 1):

The path used inside the crontab file can be different form the one defined inside your interactive shell, and many variables are not set at all.

You could add a `PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH` line to your crontab file, or just use absolute paths.

PD:If your script uses X11, you should set your `$DISPLAY` variable.